# Search by internal field in Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, filter

Structure:

```
{
    .................
    "mp": "CAR",
    "nPhoto": 1,
    "items": [
  {
    "availableQuantity": 3,
  },
        {
    "availableQuantity": 0,
  },
  {
    "availableQuantity": 0,
  }
    ],
    ............................
  }
}
```

If I filter by mp field, I generate the following query:

GET catalog/_search

```
{
  "from" : 0,
  "size" : 0,
  "aggregations" : {
    "brand" : {
      "filter" : {
        "bool" : {
          "must" : {
            "term" : {
              "mp" : "CAR"
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggregations" : {
        "photosQuantity" : { "sum" : { "field" : "nPhoto" } }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But how to generate query if you need to filter by field availableQuantity, where availableQuantity > 0 at least one of the items?

Comment: share mappings please.

Comment: {
   .............
  "mappings": {
    "product": {
      "properties": {
        "mp": {
          "include_in_all": true,
          "analyzer": "category_analyzer",
          "type": "string"
        },
        "nPhoto": {
          "include_in_all": false,
          "index": "no",
          "type": "long"
        },
        "items": {
          "properties": {
            "availableQuantity": {
              "include_in_all": false,
              "index": "no",
              "type": "long"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

Answer (score 2):

What you probably want is [nested](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html) query in filter part.

something along line of this:

```
{
  "from": 0,
  "size": 0,
  "aggregations": {
    "brand": {
      "filter": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "items",
          "query": {
            "range": {
              "items.availableQuantity": {
                "gte": 0
              }
            }
          }
        }
      },
      "aggregations": {
        "photosQuantity": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "nPhoto"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```